# How to have optional arguments for a class?

Tags: python

I'm making a chess game. Each chess piece will have different moves, in specific directions. However, not all the pieces will have moves in the different directions, so some moves are not necessary to pass in.

The pieces will be stored in a dictionary, which will have subdictionaries of the different moves.

```
class Chess:
    def __init__(self, piece, top, bottom, right, left, top_left, bottom_left, top_right, bottom_right):
        self.piece = piece
        self.top = top
        self.bottom = bottom
        self.right = right
        self.left = left

        self.top_left = top_left
        self.bottom_left = bottom_left
        self.top_right = top_right
        self.bottom_right = bottom_right




    def make_brick(self):

        piece_moves = {
            self.piece: {
                "Top": self.top
            }
        }

        return piece_moves


farmer = Chess("Farmer", 1)
print(farmer.make_brick())
```

Output:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'bottom', 'right', 'left', 'top_left', 'bottom_left', 'top_right', and 'bottom_right'
```

Comment: If you're just asking how to have optional arguments, please follow basic tutorials: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values. If not, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: To be clear: the arguments of the class (optional or otherwise) are just the (possibly optional) arguments of its `__init__` method.

Comment: Alternatively, you could represent the chess board as a 8x8 grid and a move as +/- x and y integer value pair, and pick 0,0 at one of the corners.

Answer (score 2):

Python allows for optional arguments in functions with default values. The optional argument values are assigned the default value if they are not passed in otherwise are assigned the value passed to the function. The optional arguments are also known as keyword arguments or named arguments.

The default value is specified by the syntax *parameter=expression*, where the expression can be a value, compound expression, function call, etc. This applies to any python function, not just the `__init__()` function. Define a function such that all the positional arguments are first in the argument list followed by those with default values.

```
def __init__(self, piece, top=None, bottom=None, right=None, left=None,
             top_left=None, bottom_left=None, top_right=None, bottom_right=None):
  if top is None:
    print("top not defined")
```

The initialization with 2 parameters will assign piece="Farmer" and top=1.

```
farmer = Chess("Farmer", 1)
```

To assign a parameter by name:

```
farmer = Chess("Farmer", top=1, right=3)
```

Comment: Note `=` is only _"the assignment operator"_ (not actually an operator) in an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). In a [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) the `=` has nothing to do with assignment (and still isn't an operator).

Comment: if no parameter is provided the default value is assigned but understand what you mean.

Comment: It's _used_, but it's not strictly an _assignment_. And again it's not an [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) in any of these cases (including a [call expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), for that matter), just a [delimiter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **args** or **kwargs**. However, I recomend CodeMonkey's answer over this, as it is more verbose and easier to implement and understand.